# LINQ to SQL, override dispose

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dispose, idisposable, objectdisposedexception

I am creating a LINQ to SQL DataContext by passing it an already open connection. This works, except I'm now leaking connections everywhere because although I dispose the DataContext when I'm finished, the connection never gets closed. I understand this is by design.

What I would like to do is ensure that my connection gets closed once my DataContext is disposed.

I have tried to override Dispose on the DataContext, like this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    this.Connection.Close();
}
```

However, this does not work... I get an ObjectDisposedException. Setting a breakpoint shows me that everything is already disposed at this point!

The only workaround I have found, is to hide the Dispose method on DataContext. Like this:

```
    public new void Dispose()
    {
        this.Connection.Close();

        base.Dispose();
    }
```

However, this has a bit of a bad code smell to me. What is the recommended way to proceed here?

Complete code sample (DataClasses1DataContext is an empty DataContext):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;initial catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            var ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext(connection);
            ctx.ExecuteCommand("declare @i int");

            ctx.Dispose();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public partial class DataClasses1DataContext
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // This will throw an ObjectDisposedException
        // this.Connection.Close();
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        // This will work
        // this.Connection.Close();

        //base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception on the override Dispose method call ?

Comment: I get an ObjectDisposedException

Comment: What is the message for the ObjectDisposedException?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.

Comment: The connection object, indeed all the context's properties, have already been disposed by the time I hid the Dispose(bool disposing) override. Because the Dispose() method is called first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Dispose()` sets `disposed` before calling `Dispose(bool)`. This causes the exception when you call `Connection`. There does not appear to be a way around this.

However I have to ask, why is this necessary? `Dispose(bool)` calls `Dispose` on the `Provider` which contains the `Connection` and should handle closing it automatically.

Comment: Thank you. From looking at reflector, it seems the connection is only disposed under certain conditions (probably, if it was opened by Linq to SQL in the first place).

Comment: And superficially, at least, it appears that Linq to SQL does not have a public provider model that I can just change. Seems that my workaround is the only way.

Comment: @TheNextman: Are you using the `SqlProvider`? It appears that it should always close the connection. Unless I am missing somewhere where `conManager` is getting set to `null` (it is constructed outside a branch).

Comment: It's not clear to me after reading the code in Reflector. However, the documentation (and backed up by running my sample code while using SQLServer:General Statistics:User Connections performance counter) demonstrates that, if you either give Linq to SQL an already open connection, or open it's connection object yourself, it will *not* dispose/close it in destruction

Comment: @TheNextman: Interesting, it is too bad there is no easy way to get to the connection object during `Dispose()`. Or for that matter a way to explicitly request control like how `Stream` is handled.

Comment: After some more investigation: L2S will dispose the connection if you construct the DataContext using a connection string. If you construct with a connection, it will not dispose it. Makes sense :)